# how to change the width of react player from its default

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, react-player

I am using react-player to play video in an app. And it comes with default width which is not responsive. I used some css but it does not work.

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

<ReactPlayer url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U" style={{ width: '100%' }} />
```

please tell me a way i can change its width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this .

```
  <ReactPlayer
          className='react-player'
          url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U'
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
        />
```

Comment: @kritiz if this helps than please consider this as marked and upvote the ans .

Comment: thank you , I also need to implement media queries in ReactPlayer, how can i make it happen

Comment: i have defined className so you can create seprate css file in which you can define media query .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e6w3rtj1/
example for responsive :D hope it help @kritiz

Comment: @AnhTuan happy to have helped :)  please consider this ans as marked .

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/vv19l17wj3?file=/src/index.js

```
<ReactPlayer url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U" width= '100%'/>
```

try to use width props

Answer (score 1):

```
<ReactPlayer 
     url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJj_T-GmtWM&t=1s'
     width= '150%'
/>
```

now if you use the height It will not work.